# Multiple Docker containers using identical Dockerfiles

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, microservices

In the project I've been working on, there's a few microservices, each one built from its own Dockerfile. The Dockerfiles for four of them are exactly identical:

```
#Dockerfile

FROM python:3.7

RUN pip install pip --upgrade
RUN pip install pipenv

COPY Pipfile.lock /code/Pipfile.lock
COPY Pipfile /code/Pipfile

WORKDIR /code
RUN pipenv install --system --deploy
```

The containers are built with docker-compose.

I have been given a suggestion to "do something" about these identical Dockerfiles, however I'm not sure if there's any point in it.

On the one hand, this is obviously repeated code, and I suppose I could just use one copy of the Dockerfile for all the four services (e.g. built those four containers according to the same recipe), but on the other -  I imagine that if there's need to adjust anything in one of the images in the future, the whole setup will have to be reversed again.

I haven't found any similar cases described over the internet. Is there any "good practice" in such situation? What would be the advantages (are there any?) of using a single Dockerfile?

Comment: You may create a custom BASE IMAGE which is this image for such purpose , you will not be able to get away from having seperate Dockerfile but your common code will reside in the dockerfile of the base image.

Comment: That Dockerfile is missing the `COPY` line to add application code into the image, and the `CMD` line to say how to run it.  I’d treat it as more-or-less required boilerplate, much like a `setup.py` file, and not worry about trying to deduplicate it.

Comment: @DavidMaze I guess you're probably right. There's also a docker-compose.yml file where a volume with code is added to each service. The commands are also defined there.

Answer (score 0):

you can build an image  and instead of using

#Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7

RUN pip install pip --upgrade
RUN pip install pipenv

COPY Pipfile.lock /code/Pipfile.lock
COPY Pipfile /code/Pipfile

WORKDIR /code
RUN pipenv install --system --deploy
```

#Dockerfile Replaced

```
FROM python:3.7

RUN pip install pip --upgrade
RUN pip install pipenv 
RUN mkdir /code 
WORKDIR /code
RUN pipenv install --system --deploy
```

## docker-compose

```
  service1:
    container_name: name1
    image: yourimage
    volumes:
      - ./service1/files/:/code
  service2:
    container_name: name2
    image: yourimage
    volumes:
      - ./service2/files/:/code
  service3:
    container_name: name3
    image: yourimage
    volumes:
      - ./service3/files/:/code
```